# form_for omit specific fields from @user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a user model: `:name`, `:email`, `:password`

Here is my form:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.text_field :password %>

  <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

I want to display the form without `:password`, when I remove the password attribute and submit the form, the fields do not update in the database. I get a rollback.

Comment: are you using devise?

Comment: No I am not using devise. Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial.

Comment: have you put a validation on password. your password should be present right ?

Comment: that was it, how do I prevent this validation from happening when the I'm not updating the password?

Comment: i have given one answer below, please try that

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
 object.attribute = value
 object.save(:validate => false)
```

This will never call your validation

But remember this will never validates your email and name fields as well if they are blank.

Comment: however, in other parts of the app, I allow users to update their password. in this specific form they should only be allowed to update name and email not password, but apparently the model is still validating password.

Comment: i think you are using update_atrributes and that should validate all of our fields that is having model level validation

Answer (score 0):

Commenting this line in my user model fixed the issue:
`validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }`

However, as noted in the comments, it is not sufficient. 
A user can edit their own profile, an admin can edit their own and others profiles.

Here is a solution:

```
  def update
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    if current_user?(@user)
      if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
        flash[:success] = "Your profile updated"
        redirect_to @user
      else
          render 'edit'
      end
    else
      if @user.update_attributes(admin_params)
        flash[:success] = "Others profile updated"
        redirect_to @user
      else
          render 'admin_edit_user'
      end
    end
  end

private

def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password)                           
end

def admin_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password) if current_user.admin?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip validations on a particular form for a particular attribute, you could do the following.

```
Class User
  attr_accessor :skip_password_validation
  validate_presence_of :password, unless: -> { skip_password_validation }
end
```

This creates a virtual attribute that you can set and read but won't get persisted in the database.

Then you can put a hidden field for `:skip_password_validation` in whatever form you want and it will skip the validations.

```
<%= f.hidden_field :skip_password_validation, value: true %>
```

You'll also have to add this param to the user_params in the controller.